# RHEL 6 - installed 'GLIBC_2.14' But still Yum error

Tags: glibc, rhel6

Followed the how to guides all compiled sweet :)

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib Set

```
strings libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.2.6
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.3.3
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_2.13
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

But doing a Yum update

Error: Package: libzstd-1.3.4-1.el7.x86_64 (mariadb)
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)

I have read about changing symbolic link etc but

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explains why setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to select a different GLIBC version can not work.

Whatever how to guides you are reading are *wrong*.